# How can I make that the depth of field focus will stay on the object/s that are focused when starting the game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Screenshot of the scene when running the game first time.
The focus is on the red cube.

[image: Red is in focus]

On the Focus Camera there is a script attached name FocusSwither :

[image: Focus Camera]

On each cube Red,Blue,Green there is a script attached name FocusMe :

[image: Red Cube with the script]

If the mouse is move over the Green cube or the Blue cube the other will get blue and the cube with the mouse over will get focus :

[image: Focus on the blue cube the mouse is over the blue cube]

This is the FocusSwither script :

```
using UnityEngine;

public class FocusSwitcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string FocusedLayer = "Focused";

    private GameObject currentlyFocused;
    private int previousLayer;

    public void SetFocused(GameObject obj)
    {
        // enables this camera and the postProcessingVolume which is the child
        gameObject.SetActive(true);

        // if something else was focused before reset it
        if (currentlyFocused) currentlyFocused.layer = previousLayer;

        // store and focus the new object
        currentlyFocused = obj;

        if (currentlyFocused)
        {
            previousLayer = currentlyFocused.layer;
            currentlyFocused.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer(FocusedLayer);
        }
        else
        {
            // if no object is focused disable the FocusCamera
            // and PostProcessingVolume for not wasting rendering resources
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    // On disable make sure to reset the current object
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        if (currentlyFocused) currentlyFocused.layer = previousLayer;

        currentlyFocused = null;
    }
}
```

And the FocusMe script :

```
using UnityEngine;

public class FocusMe : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool useMouse = true;

    [SerializeField] private FocusSwitcher focus;

    private void Start()
    {
        if(useMouse == false)
        {
            focus.SetFocused(gameObject);
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
       
    }

    private void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        if (useMouse == true)
        {
            focus.SetFocused(gameObject);
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseExit()
    {
        // reset the focus
        // in the future you should maybe check first
        // if this object is actually the focused one currently
        if (useMouse == true)
        {
            focus.SetFocused(null);
        }
        else
        {
            focus.SetFocused(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I move the mouse out from the blue or green cubes and they are not in focus anymore then nothing is in focus I mean everything is back to normal to focus nothing is blur.

but I want that if the mouse was over the blue cube and now the blue cube is in focus or the green is in focus and I move the mouse then that it will be back to the default mode when running the game. So the red cube will be automatic in focus like in the second screenshot.
So if the mouse is over the blue or green make them in focus but if the mouse is not on any of the cubes make the red in focus like in the second screenshot.

In the editor I set the bool flag on the red cube useMouse to false and on the blue and green cubes the flag is set to true.

I tried first to do something in the Update then tried now something in the OnMouseExit :

```
private void OnMouseExit()
    {
        // reset the focus
        // in the future you should maybe check first
        // if this object is actually the focused one currently
        if (useMouse == true)
        {
            focus.SetFocused(null);
        }
        else
        {
            focus.SetFocused(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

I tried to add the part :

```
else
            {
                focus.SetFocused(gameObject);
            }
```

but this is not what I want. I want that the mouse is not over no any of the cubes it will return to the default starting mode when the red cube was in focus.

Answer (score 0):

You should have your red cube in your FocusMe script, and then switch the focus on it on mouse exit, something like this

```
public class FocusMe : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...

    public GameObject redCube;

    ...

    private void OnMouseExit()
    {
        focus.SetFocused(redCube);
    }
}
```

And don't forget to link your red cube to your FocusMe components on inspector.

Good Luck.